# displaying filter results, original data in same separate windows in same tab in emeditor

Tags: emeditor

i want to display filter results, original  data in different windows (top, bottom) in the same tab in em editor. is it possible in em editor?
this feature i have not seen in em editor.
as of now, if i apply filter in em editor only filter results will be shown in the same document hiding original data.
but i want to display original data, filtered data in separate windows but in the same tab. you may keep filtered data in bottom window. original data in top window. but all windows should be visible.
please help me.

Comment: like analyze plugin of notepad++. where you can see search window, search results and original data all can be seen in one tab only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show multiple documents in a same tab. However, you can use the `New Horizontal/Vertical Group` command in the `Window` menu (or right-click on a tab as shown in the screenshot) to show two windows side-by-side. By default, EmEditor makes these two windows bond together (if you activate or iconize one window, the other window will be automatically activated or iconized).

[image: EmEditor - right-click on tab]

Comment: this answer is not upto the mark. is it possible to show them in one document only using a macro. or show the filter results in output window at the bottom please.

Comment: whenever filter is applied, results should be shown in output window or log window in the same document.

Comment: can you direct filter results to output window using a macro please.

Comment: i got the solution. document.selection.SelectAll();  // select all text

document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode);  // copy the seleciton to the Clipboard
str = clipboardData.getData(document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode));

OutputBar.Clear();

OutputBar.writeln(str);

OutputBar.Visible = true;

OutputBar.SetFocus();

Comment: this is the solution i have made. if there is any better solution please share me. document.selection.BatchFind(batch_list,  eeFindExtract | eeFindLineOnly,0);
document.selection.SelectAll();  // select all text

document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode);  // copy the seleciton to the Clipboard
str = clipboardData.getData(document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode));

OutputBar.Clear();

OutputBar.writeln(str);

OutputBar.Visible = true;

OutputBar.SetFocus();

editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4120);